Error 500 / page expired / missing response cookies for LARAVEL APP in XAMPP
I have some issue by running my laravel app in XAMPP. So I have 2 scenarios:

Running app on php artisan serve - I do not get any error here
Running app on XAMPP on localhost:4000

So I have a page with a counter (livewire component), and each time I press a button counter number increases. After a few requests I'm getting error 500.
TRIED:
1. Check cookies: SESSION COOKIE and CSRF TOKEN
SESSION_DRIVER=file
I have been looking at the requests and what I found out is that I am missing some cookies when I get the error.
Here I get only the request cookies, and also 500 Internal Server Error
nok request
On this one everything is fine, I get request and response cookies request ok
So this issue is pretty much random, sometimes I get the error after 5 requests, sometimes after 20. (tested up to 150 requests manually and did not get any error on php artisan serve)
2. Check logs and disable CSRF
So this is what I found in my logs file
production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Encryption\MissingAppKeyException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at C:\xampp\htdocs\{appname}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:83)
I have tried by commenting the CSRF in Kernel.php but same result ( \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class), guess I should not do this anyway but had to test it out :D
3. Modify php.ini
output_buffering = 4096 - changing it to higher value, found this solution somewhere but still not helping
4. ENV file
Also tryed to play a bit with the .ENV file by changing values for SESSION_COOKIE, SESSION_DOMAIN, SESSION_PATH but still ran into the same error
My guess is that it might be some memory problem in XAMPP since it is working well on php artisan serve. Up for suggestions, thank you!

I didn't read the complete question, But for this No application encryption key has been specified. you can run key:generate command. It will set in .env

the key is not the problem, it is some server settings problem I think. I have a key but at some requests I'm not getting the RESPONSE COOKIES so I get the No application encryption key has been specified

As you said: It runs with serve, not in XAMPP. for Laravel development, XAMPP is not really a good choice.

so what should I use then for a local server? atm I'm using laravel 11

After many more things tried I got to the solution for the problem: php artisan config:cache
